# How do I use purrr::map with dataframe list to modify column values in specific dataframes without changing other dataframes in list?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

- I have a list of many data frames (`survey08`, `survey09`,
  `survey10`, etc.) called `df_list`.
- Each data frame contains 2 columns named `year`and `employed`.

```r
# create 3 dataframes with identical column names
survey08 <- data.frame(year = 2008, employed = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2))
survey09 <- data.frame(year = 2009, employed = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1))
survey10 <- data.frame(year = 2010, employed = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1))

# put dataframes into a list
df_list <- list(survey08, survey09, survey10)

# add names for dataframes in list
# names correspond to survey year ('year' column)
names(df_list) <- c("survey08", "survey09", "survey10")
```

I want to recode values in the `employed` column (1 = yes, 2 = no) but only in the `survey08` and `survey09` data frames. For other data frames in the list, I want to retain the original column values (i.e., only modify specific DFs in the list).

I tried the following code, using the `year` column as a filter:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# modify only values in 'employed' column for DFs 'survey08' and 'survey09' 
# use 'year' column as filter

df_list %>% 
  map(~filter(.x, year %in% 2008:2009)) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), ~recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")))
```

While this correctly recodes two data frames (`survey08` and `survey09`), it doesn't retain values from other data frames in the list.

**Current output:**

```r
#> $survey08
#>   year employed
#> 1 2008      yes
#> 2 2008       no
#> 3 2008       no
#> 4 2008      yes
#> 5 2008       no
#> 
#> $survey09
#>   year employed
#> 1 2009      yes
#> 2 2009      yes
#> 3 2009      yes
#> 4 2009       no
#> 5 2009      yes
#> 
#> $survey10
#> [1] year     employed
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Desired output:**

```r
$survey08
  year employed
1 2008      yes
2 2008       no
3 2008       no
4 2008      yes
5 2008       no

$survey09
  year employed
1 2009      yes
2 2009      yes
3 2009      yes
4 2009       no
5 2009      yes

$survey10
  year employed
1 2010      2
2 2010      1
3 2010      1
4 2010      1
5 2010      1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map_at` which only modifies elements given by names or positions.

```
df_list %>% 
  map_at(c("survey08", "survey09"),
         ~ filter(.x, year %in% 2008:2009)) %>% 
  map_at(c("survey08", "survey09"),
         ~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), 
         ~ recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")))

$`survey08`
  year employed
1 2008      yes
2 2008       no
3 2008       no
4 2008      yes
5 2008       no

$survey09
  year employed
1 2009      yes
2 2009      yes
3 2009      yes
4 2009       no
5 2009      yes

$survey10
  year employed
1 2010        2
2 2010        1
3 2010        1
4 2010        1
5 2010        1
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use both `map_at()` statements? Seems to work with just: `df_list  %>% map_at(c("survey08", "survey09"), ~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), ~ recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")))`

Comment: @JohnnySullivan It's not necessary. I wasn't sure of the purpose of `filter` so just kept it as is.

Answer (score 2):

using `filter` will remove the other data.frames that you want to keep. You want the `map_if` instead of `map`. Then you can use the `.p` to identify items to perform the map function on.

```
df_list %>% 
   map_if(., 
      .f = ~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), ~recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")), 
      .p = c(T,T,F))
```

or

```
df_list %>% 
   map_if(., 
       .f = ~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), ~recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")), 
       .p = ~ .x %>% pull(year) %>% unique(.) %in% 2008:2009)
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution using `lapply` and a user-defined function assessing if `year` is smaller than `2010`.

```
df_list2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x){
  if (unique(x$year) < 2010){
    x$employed <- as.character(factor(x$employed, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("yes", "no")))
  }
  return(x)
})

df_list2
# $survey08
#   year employed
# 1 2008      yes
# 2 2008       no
# 3 2008       no
# 4 2008      yes
# 5 2008       no
# 
# $survey09
#   year employed
# 1 2009      yes
# 2 2009      yes
# 3 2009      yes
# 4 2009       no
# 5 2009      yes
# 
# $survey10
#   year employed
# 1 2010        2
# 2 2010        1
# 3 2010        1
# 4 2010        1
# 5 2010        1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which list you want to perform the manipulation why not subset only those and recode them.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list[c("survey08", "survey09")] <- df_list[c("survey08", "survey09")] %>%
  map(~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(employed), ~recode_factor(.,`1` = "yes", `2` = "no")))


df_list
#$survey08
#  year employed
#1 2008      yes
#2 2008       no
#3 2008       no
#4 2008      yes
#5 2008       no

#$survey09
#  year employed
#1 2009      yes
#2 2009      yes
#3 2009      yes
#4 2009       no
#5 2009      yes

#$survey10
#  year employed
#1 2010        2
#2 2010        1
#3 2010        1
#4 2010        1
#5 2010        1
```